# How to pass a nested function to an HTML button and Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I have two major functions getChart() and fetchdata() and they get the chart data and my x and y axes data from database respectively. I want to use a function inside my getChart for my dropdown menu to display different types of charts when clicked on them. Can someone help me out. Thanks

```
<body>
<div class="chartMenu">
    <p>Loan Applications Accepted</p>
    <div class="chartCard">
        <div class="chartBox">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            
            <button onclick="(new getChart()).back();"> GO BACK </button>
            <select onchange="(new start()).changeChart();">
                <optgroup label="Select Chart"></optgroup>
                <option value="bar">Bar</option>
                <option value="pie">Pie</option>
                <option value="line">Line</option>
                 <option value="doughnut">Doughnut</option>
              </select>
```

function fetchData(url) {
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "GET",

```
                    success: function (data) {
                        coordinates = [];
                        // console.log(data);
                        Array.from(data).forEach(element => {
                            coordinates.push({ x: element.x_axis, y: element.y_axis })
                            console.log(coordinates)

                        });


                        getChart();

                    },

                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
                    }
                });






            };
```

function getChart() {

```
      //setup block
      var data = {

        datasets: [{
          label: 'No of Loan Applications',
          data: coordinates,

          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(193, 32, 32, 0.58)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.58)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.58)',
            'rgba(153, 167, 64, 0.58)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.58)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.58)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58)',
            'rgba(167, 40, 145, 0.58)',
            'rgba(0, 184, 223, 0.58)',
            'rgba(70, 216, 59, 0.58)',
            'rgba(255, 231, 59, 0.58)',
            'rgba(18, 228, 184, 0.58)'



          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            'rgba(167, 40, 145, 0.8)',
            'rgba(0, 184, 223, 0.8)',
            'rgba(70, 216, 59, 0.54)',
            'rgba(255, 231, 59, 0.86)',
            'rgba(18, 228, 184, 0.59)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]

      };

      //config block
      var config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {

          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              grace: 1,
              ticks: {

                precision: 0,


              }

            },


          },

        }


      };


      //render block
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

      let myChart = new Chart(
        ctx,
        config

      );



      this.back = function () {
          if (myChart != null) {
              myChart.destroy();
          }
          fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=1')
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
          myChart.update();
      };


      function clickHandler(click) {


        const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(click, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
        if (points.length) {
          const firstPoint = points[0];
          console.log(firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x)

          if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2020") {

            fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2020')
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
            myChart.update();



          }

          else if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2021") {

            fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2021')
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
            myChart.update();

          }

          else if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2022") {

            fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2022')
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
            myChart.update();

          }



          else {
            console.log("Wrong input");
          }

        }
      };
      ctx.onclick = clickHandler;

      function changeChart(chartType) {
        console.log(chartType);
        console.log(chartType.value);
      }

      function start() {
        getChart();
        clickHandler(click);
        changeChart(chartType)
      }

      start();

    };

    $(document).ready(fetchData(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening.

You are calling `getChart()`, which is calling `start()`, and in `start()` you are calling `getChart()`!! You are making an infinite recursion, but it actually is stopping on the second call of `getChart()` because the chart is not beeing destroyed.

First, just make every function out of getChart, and remove the recursion.

Now, set the select to the following:

```
<select id="types">
```

and in your javascript add the folowing to take the change event:

```
$(function () {
    // on change the type of the chart
    $(document).on("change", "#types", function () {
        let type = $('#types').val();
        changeChart(type);
    });
})
```

Now changing the type of a chart. First you need to destroy the chart, Then you can recreate a chart with the type that is selected.

```
function changeChart(newType) {
    if (chart) {
        chart.destroy();
    }
    myChart= new Chart("myChart", {
        type: newType,
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```