# How to pass a function inside another function to an HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I have two major functions fetchData() and getChart() they fetch data from my DB and have chart data(datasets, config, options etc.) respectively. Inside my getChart() I have 3 functions namely clickHandler(), back() and changeChart(). I am using a button where after the click is triggered my back() function should show the primary chart (I am doing a deep dive chart where as and when i click on the bars of the chart, the chart updates to a new one). For my changeChart() i will be using a dropdown menu to choose the type of chart.

I am not able to figure out a way of calling the functions inside my getChart() to my HTML attributes. Also, I am using ChartJS and I am an amateur in JS. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
function getChart() {
  //setup block
  var data = {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'No of Loan Applications',
      data: coordinates,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(193, 32, 32, 0.58)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.58)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.58)',
        'rgba(153, 167, 64, 0.58)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.58)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.58)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58)',
        'rgba(167, 40, 145, 0.58)',
        'rgba(0, 184, 223, 0.58)',
        'rgba(70, 216, 59, 0.58)',
        'rgba(255, 231, 59, 0.58)',
        'rgba(18, 228, 184, 0.58)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        'rgba(167, 40, 145, 0.8)',
        'rgba(0, 184, 223, 0.8)',
        'rgba(70, 216, 59, 0.54)',
        'rgba(255, 231, 59, 0.86)',
        'rgba(18, 228, 184, 0.59)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  };

  //config block
  var config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          grace: 1,
          ticks: {
            precision: 0,
          }
        },
      },
    }
  };

  //render block
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  let myChart = new Chart(
    ctx,
    config
  );

  function back() {
    if (myChart != null) {
      myChart.destroy();
    }
    fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=1')
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
    myChart.update();
  };

  function clickHandler(click) {
    const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(click, 'nearest', {
      intersect: true
    }, true);
    if (points.length) {
      const firstPoint = points[0];
      console.log(firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x)

      if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2020") {
        fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2020')
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
        myChart.update();
      } else if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2021") {
        fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2021')
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
        myChart.update();
      } else if (firstPoint.element.$context.raw.x == "2022") {
        fetchData('http://localhost:8080/jsonGet?year=2022')
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = coordinates;
        myChart.update();
      } else {
        console.log("Wrong input");
      }
    }
  };
  ctx.onclick = clickHandler;

  function changeChart(chartType) {
    console.log(chartType);
    console.log(chartType.value);
  }
};

$(document).ready(fetchData(url));
```

THIS IS MY HTML PART: ITS NOT COMPLETE

```
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <!-- <button onclick="fetchData()">Fetch Now</button> -->
    <!-- <button onclick="getChart()"> Get Chart</button> -->
    <button onclick="(new getChart()).back();"> GO BACK </button>
    <select onchange="(new getChart()).changeChart(this)">
      <optgroup label="Select Chart"></optgroup>
      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
      <option value="pie">Pie</option>
      <option value="line">Line</option>
      <option value="doughnut">Doughnut</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a nested function to an HTML button and Dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459871/how-to-pass-a-nested-function-to-an-html-button-and-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own posts

Comment: Im sorry, that was my work email and I was not supposed to ask questions from that. I guess i deleted it.

Comment: That question was not framed properly as well by my colleague